# Material js radio button disable not working after upgrading Jquery to 3.4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, material-design

I have upgraded jquery version to 3.4 and material.js version 1.1.0. After upgrading jquery version to 3.4
$(".id").attr("disabled", "disabled"); not working. It is working in some versions of chrome browser, my version is  83.0.4103.116.
The disabled attribute is correctly removed and added but the disable style is not get applied on the radio button.
If we hard code disabled in html it is working fine
Sample Code:

```
 <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="RadioButton">
 <input id="RadioButton" type="radio" class="mdl-radio__button" name="approve" value="Radiobutton">
 <span class="mdl-radio__label">Radio</span>
 </label>
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#RadioButton").removeAttr("disabled");
if(condition)
$("#RadioButton").prop("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

In js file i have added like this
Normal radio button is working but after using material radio button(***mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect using this class***) is not woring

Answer (score -1):

i would recommend using this instead for newer versions of jquery it is the better approach

```
$("#RadioButton").prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: I have tried .prop also, but it is not working for me, But the same code is working in other system with same version of chrome